# C# Unity How to print out a dictionary in order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I manage to do something like this

`
Heli Takedown >

playername | 10

playername | 19

playername | 23
etc..
`

I am storing the Player and damage done in a dictionary, just finding it hard to take it all out and then print it into a message and only print the top 5 players who did the most damage.
Code:

```
        private void SendHeliMessage()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<BasePlayer, int> hitInfo in HeliHits)
            {
                BasePlayer Player = hitInfo.Key;
                int DamageDone = hitInfo.Value;
                var players = HeliHits.Keys;
                SendMessage(Player,$"this is a test, Heli Takedown >\n\n{0} | {1}", null, 0, Player.displayName, string.Join("\n", DamageDone));
            }
        }
        void SendMessage(BasePlayer player, string message, params object[] args)
        {
            PrintToChat(player, message, args);
        }
```

(Yes i know what I have is wrong it was me just messing around and testing)

Comment: You cannot. A dictionary is _by design_ an unordered collection. You can extract all values from the dictionary and sort them manually or you could use a different container type. `OrderedDictionary` is not generic, so I wouldn't recommend it, but what else might be suitable depends on your requirements.

Comment: Would an Array be better to use?

Answer (score 1):

To sort the dictionary by Value from highest to lowest may look something like…

```
var sorted = HeliHits.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value);
```

Then to loop through the dictionary and output all the Key Value pairs may look something like…

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<BasePlayer, int> hitInfo in sorted) {
    SendMessage(hitInfo.Key, $"this is a test, Heli Takedown >\n\n{0} | {1}", hitInfo.Key.displayName, string.Join("\n", hitInfo.Value));
}
```

If you wanted only the top 5 values in the dictionary then you could do something like….

```
var sorted = HeliHits.OrderByDescending(key => key.Value).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not seeing the obvious initially. A dictionary is by design unordered, but of course you can iterate over it in a ordered way by explicitly requesting an ordered enumeration:

```cs
private void SendHeliMessage()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<BasePlayer, int> hitInfo in HeliHits.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)) // Get players with their score ordered from the best to the worst
            {
                BasePlayer Player = hitInfo.Key;
                int DamageDone = hitInfo.Value;
                var players = HeliHits.Keys;
                SendMessage(Player, $"this is a test, Heli Takedown >\n\n{0} | {1}", null, 0, Player.displayName, string.Join("\n", DamageDone));
            }
        }
```

To get a single message:

```cs
   private void SendHeliMessage()
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            int rank = 1;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<BasePlayer, int> hitInfo in HeliHits.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)) // Get players with their score ordered from the best to the worst
            {
                BasePlayer Player = hitInfo.Key;
                int DamageDone = hitInfo.Value;
                var players = HeliHits.Keys;
                result.Append($"Rank {rank}: Player {Player.displayName} with {DamageDone} points");
                rank++;
            }
            SendMessage(Player, result.ToString(), null, 0, Player.displayName, string.Empty);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, would the message display all there names though? I'm only new to strings and I had a mess around with StringBuilder but I wasn't sure what I was doing.

Comment: Because its only get a 'Key' not Keys so i was thinking it will send the message many times since its in a foreach loop, when i only want it to send all the names in one message. Hopfully you understand that

Comment: StringBuilder is a good approach for this problem, see my example. This just joins the strings together before sending a single message.

Comment: Ah yeah, but then how can I use Player.displayName for SendMessage when it is outside of the Foreach loop where the variable is made?

Comment: Because BasePlayer is a local variable and I can't put it outside of the method because then it wont get the single Key or in this case the Player because I'm using KeyValuePair

Comment: True, that doesn't work. I don't know the exact syntax of that SendMessage method, but I guess that's just a title and you can put anything there.

Comment: Well if i put the SendMessage within the SendHeliMessage then it will just send a lot, when i only want it to send once

Comment: You didn't give enough context to give you further advice. Where is that method being called from?

Comment: If you check the original message and at the bottom of it.

Comment: This does not indicate where `SendHeliMessage` is being called from. If my last suggestion still outputs the message to often, then this function is called more than once.

Comment: Ah ok, here is the whole file
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/791886852617535510/968396709975715850/unknown.png

Comment: Looks right to me, `OnEntityDeath` is supposedly only called once, so this should be fine. I'm not an unity expert, though.